# Get all values from specific column without duplicates

Tags: jquery, each

I need to use Jquery to get all values from a specific column (header "Comp", in different positions) without duplicates.

My tables:

```
<table>
  <thead class="tableh">
    <tr> <th>Key</th><th>Comp</th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

 <tr><td>CA5533</td><td>1413</td></tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead class="tableh">
    <tr> <th>Key</th><th>Sec</th><th>Comp</th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

 <tr><td>CA5533</td><td>1413</td><td>1413</td></tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

My function (not working):

```
var arr = [];
$(".tableh th:contains('Comp')").each(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(".tableh th:contains('Comp') td").text(), arr) == -1)
        arr.push($(".tableh th:contains('Comp') td").text());
});

//Create your select
var select = $("<select />");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $("<option>" + arr[i] + "</option>").appendTo(select);
}

select.appendTo("#whitebginternal");
```

Anyone here who can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can first find the index of the `Comp` row from the value in the `th`. Then you can build an array of all the text values in the `td` elements in that column, before looping through that array to place the `option` elements in the `select`.

Also note that as you've stated you have multiple tables in the page, you'll need to loop through each one, something like this:

```js
$('table:has(thead.tableh)').each(function() {
  var index = $(this).find('.tableh th:contains("Comp")').index();
  var options = $(this).find('tbody tr').find('td:eq(' + index + ')').map(function() {
    return `<option>${$(this).text()}</option>`;
  }).get().join('');

  $("#whitebginternal").append(`<select>${options}</select>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead class="tableh">
    <tr>
      <th>Key</th>
      <th>Comp</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>CA5533</td>
      <td>1413</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CA5534</td>
      <td>1414</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CA5535</td>
      <td>1415</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CA5536</td>
      <td>1416</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="whitebginternal"></div>
```

Comment: Great, Rory! With one table your function works great. The problem is: I have more tables, with variable number of columns. Any other idea?

Comment: This code will still work for them. It's keyed by the `Comp` value in the `th` element.

Comment: The problem is to use `find` with `eq`. My columns are in different positions. (I've edited the post)

Comment: That makes no difference. As I said, it will look for values in whatever column that the `Comp` header is in.

Comment: @ZecaNovaes Are you saying that for a given table, the index of the value you want in each row does not always correspond to the index of the header? If not, this should work.

Comment: I've tested this function and I get the values of the second column only. My second table have "Comp" as third column.

Comment: Do you have multiple tables with the `thead.tableh` element?

Comment: Yeah. With "Comp" in different positions inside the tables.

Comment: Ok, that's an important distinction. I updated the answer for you. Here's a working 'multi-table' fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/erc6n5d1/

Comment: To avoid duplicate values, any changes needed?